# Displays sporadically experience flapping/intermittent issue with intermittent power

Tags: multiple-monitors, power-supply, hdmi

I do own a PC with the following configs.

- Gigabyte - 1050Ti
- 450 w Powersupply
- 2x 23" Dell LED monitors
- 1.2KWh UPS

But with intermittent power in some occasions, the screens to becomes flapping/intermittent.

By “flapping/intermittent” I mean the screen. doesn't show anything. But it does for a little while (around 1-4 seconds). It's blank for that time. But returns back to a live screen soon afterwards.

However it doesn't seem to be directly connected to power from the monitor, as with flapping/intermittency it doesn't load the loading symbol (Dell logo) in the screen, instead it's around 2-4 seconds of flap/intermittency with screen returning.

But I do have doubts over whether the reason can be with the power supply unit being insufficient (EzCool) to handle them. But the case here is that usually one monitor is seeming to cause the trouble, and it becomes both in some occasions.

I have currently tried the following:

- Changing the HDMI cables
- Interchanging HDMI cables

However nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Screen doesn't show anything. But it is for a little while (around 1-4 seconds). It's blank for that time. But returns back live soon

Comment: Okay, that last comment makes sense. I have edited your question further to work that description into the body.

Comment: Yeah, Im coming from an app support background. So apologies from my end with my word usage. Thanks for the new edit.